# Linux steam client cannot display Chinese character

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, steam

I am using fedora 38 and GNOME 44, I have installed steam, while I discover the chinese font are not render properly, what should I config to fix the issue?
The font render break in whole steam client, but chinese font can be render outside steam.
Screenshot:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you install steam? It should have brought you a sufficiently complete runtime containing the necessary fonts. If this is vendor packaging, or say flatpak, you'll have to raise a bug report with the vendor or with the flatpak packager.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package wqy-zenhei-font can render Asian font correctly

You can install it via dnf:

```
dnf install steam wqy-zenhei-font
```

I have encounter the same problem and the text render correctly after install this package.